# oracle sum of many rows - the value of a single row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do some math in oracle that has me returning the sum of many rows, minus a value of 1 row in a different column on that same table. Is this possible?

For example,

select sum(column1) - (select column2 from table1 where month = to_date(201505, 'yyyymm'))
from table1
where month >= to_date(201006, 'yyyymm');

Comment: Have you tried your query? Have you got an error or an unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @Aleksej: was about to type the exact same sentence .. O.o   But also adding, just needs to make sure `where month = to_date(201505, 'yyyymm')` results in a single row ... but .. uh .. yeah .. :)

Comment: don't post queries in comments, impossible to read .. if it's relevant .. post it in the original post ..

Comment: You are using a group function (`SUM`) without any grouping; you need to add a `GROUP BY` clause, grouping by `LS_ASSET_ID`; besides, as DItto said, are you sure that the subquery will return exactly ONE value? otherwise you need to modify it with a `MIN`, `MAX` or whatever you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to cross-join with the subquery.

```
select
    s.sum1 - t.column2
from (select sum(column1) as sum1 from table1 where month >= to_date('201006','yyyymm') ) s
cross join (select column2 from table1 where month = to_date('201505','yyyymm')) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe it would be possible. Given that you can identify the row with the other column that has the value to be subtracted you can use the [aggregate 'sum'](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions163.htm) in conjunction with a ['case' statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm#i36967).

If the condition matches, subtract the relevant column two from column-one else do not subtract and use the original value in the column-one for the 'sum' funcion.

It would look something like this :

```
select 
sum( 
    case (when <condition-normal>) then 
        column_one 
    else 
        column_two - column_one 
        )
) from table;
```

PS: Be sure to test it out against different sets of data!